# Invalid tuple size in creation of Decimal from list or tuple

Tags: python, django, csv

Hello im uploading a csv file to my model, but my model have decimal fields, and when i try to upload the file it throws this error

> Invalid tuple size in creation of Decimal from list or tuple.  The
>   list or tuple should have exactly three elements.

i've try everything, like, for example decimal(row[13]), and it doenst work, also i coded this function which is throwing the error

```
def to_decimal(row):
if not(row):
    row = 0
    row2 = Decimal(row)
else:
    row2 = Decimal(row)
    print row2
return row2
```

what can i do?? the csv file is correct, and could have empty rows,

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using a global variable `row` that is multidimensional. It is the only explanation as to why `row[13]` would continue to throw such and error. Anyway, I found some courseware that may be useful with parsing CSV files [here](https://www.udacity.com/course/ud032). You may have to skip around to find the specific video.